# Checking if class T has member type Member with void_t

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, sfinae

So here's the code:

```
template<typename, typename, typename = void>
struct has_member_type : false_type {};

template<typename T, typename Member>
struct has_member_type<T, Member, void_t<typename T::Member>> : true_type {};

struct foo { using bar = int; };

int main()
{
    std::cout << has_member_type<foo, typename foo::bar>::value;
}
```

I'm trying to check whether `foo` has a `bar` type member. It works fine if the implementation doesn't specify the type member's name, but that way the name is hardcoded into the implementation, which doesn't work for me.

The question said to be duplicate doesn't come close to answering my question. As I explained in the paragraph above, it's fine when the type is hardcoded into the implementation, but I can't get it to work when I specify the type from outside (that's the specific problem). The code compiles fine, but produces wrong results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `typename foo::bar` just directly resolves to `int`, rather than passing in some construct you can use for SFINAE.

A possible solution is to make an alias template which will tell you what the type of `T::bar` is, then pass that into your checker. This is what [`std::experimental::is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) does. Here is a simplified version which is close to what you had already*:

```
template<typename, template <typename> class, typename = void>
struct is_detected : false_type {};

template<typename T, template <typename> class Op>
struct is_detected<T, Op, void_t<Op<T>>> : true_type {};
```

Then you write your alias template which you want to detect:

```
template <typename T> using bar_t = typename T::bar;
```

And usage looks like this:

```
is_detected <foo, bar_t>::value
```

*: I kept the template parameters the same way around as in your sample code so that you can easily compare. Flipping them around so that you can make the operator arguments variadic is better in a more generic context. It would also make it easier to migrate to `std::experimental::is_detected` when available for you.

Comment: This way, he needs an auxiliary template `bar_t`, right?

Comment: @Columbo Yes, `bar_t` is in my answer.

Comment: The point is that he is precisely trying to avoid any additional entities for each name. `bar_t` is part of the implementation he doesn't want hardcoded names in.

Comment: @Columbo I took "hardcoded into the implementation" to be in the `has_member_type` trait.

Comment: better to mimic `std::experimental::is_detected<Op, Args>` instead of `is_detected<Args, Op>` as you've written here, makes it easer to drop-in the `<experimental/type_traits>` header when it become available on the OP's system

Comment: @TemplateRex I kept the arguments that way round so that OP could easily compare this solution to his original code. I'll mention that in the answer.

Comment: Isn't there a way to remove the need for the `using bar_t = ...` part?

Comment: @TheBadger Not really; you need a template so that it SFINAEs when you instantiate it with a bad type.

Answer (score 2):

Once [N4487](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf) gets accepted, you'll be able to employ generic lambdas in constant expressions:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
constexpr auto test(F f) -> decltype(f(std::declval<T&>()), true) {return true;}

template <typename, typename... F>
constexpr bool test(F...) {return false;}

#define HAS_DATA(Name, ...) (test<__VA_ARGS__>([] (auto& t) -> decltype(&std::decay_t<decltype(t)>::Name) {}))
#define HAS_TYPE(Name, ...) (test<__VA_ARGS__>([] (auto& t) -> typename std::decay_t<decltype(t)>::Name {}))
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67a90668a2189eef) with `cout`.

Comment: Nice, but should return an `integral_constant` instead.

Comment: So it can be passed to parameters of functions and that value can be used in overloading(such as tag dispatching) and in `static_assert`. In addition, it can be cleaner in some cases. For example, passing it in as a template parameter for member functions requires `.template` to disambiguate it, whereas passing it as a function parameter does not.

Comment: @Paul If you use tag dispatching, encapsulate the result value in `bool_constant`. I don't see why the application of a macro named "HAS_..." should return something other than a `bool`.

Comment: But why require the user to use `bool_constant`? In addition, type traits already work this way. So why make `HAS_*` less capable by returning a raw `bool`? There is no advantage.

Comment: @Paul HAS_ is not less capable of anything. And `integral_constant` is a C++11 remnant. With concepts and variable templates, idiomatic semantics change. You'll write `requires HAS_TYPE(T, bar)`. If you want to write `requires HAS_TYPE(T, bar)::value` instead, well, that's your choice.. but I won't impose it on future C++17 readers.

Comment: It is less capable, as a raw `bool` cannot be used in many constructs in C++(I have explained earlier). Also, template variables doesn't change that, they can be template variables to `integral_constant` Unfortunately, concepts does not work with `integral_constant`, so in C++ you currently write `enable_if<(HAS_TYPE(T, bar))>` or `static_assert(HAS_TYPE(T, bar))` however in concepts you have to write `requires bool{HAS_TYPE(T, bar)}`. Hopefully this changes in the future. Either way, APIs shouldn't be built less capable because newer C++ features are less capable.